# MySQL Query with left join, group by and order by extremely slow

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query, which takes around 15 seconds to execute. If I remove the ORDER BY, it takes 3 seconds, which is still way too long.

```
SELECT
 pages.id AS id,
 pages.page_title AS name,
 SUM(visitors.bounce) AS bounce,
 SUM(visitors.goal) AS goal,
 count(visitors.id) AS volume
FROM
 pages
LEFT JOIN visitors ON pages.id = visitors.page_id
GROUP BY pages.id
ORDER BY volume DESC
```

For readability, I slightly simplified this query from the one used in the application, but I've been testing with this simplified query and the problem does still exists. So the problem is in this part.

Table pages: around 3K records. Table visitors: around 300K records.

What I have done:

- I have indexes on visitors.page_id (with external key linking to pages.id).
- Obviously my ID fields are set as primary key.

What I have tried:

- I have increased the read_buffer_size, sort_buffer_size, read_rnd_buffer_size, to 64M.
- EXPLAIN query with sorting (15 secs):
  [image]
- EXPLAIN query without sorting (3 secs, still way to long and that's not the output I want):
  [image]
- Remove the SUM and Count calculations, they didn't really have an effect on the execution time.

Any ideas to improve this query?

Comment: Databases can't magically make everything faster. Your query requires full scans of 2 tables because it has to fetch all rows no matter what you do. That's gonna take a couple seconds for a 300k row table. Additionally, the plans appear to show `WHERE` clauses even though your query doesn't have one. Are you sure you `EXPLAIN`ed this query exactly? Can you cache the result every few minutes and deliver that to the client instead?

Comment: It is indeed a bit more complex, there are a few filters that can be set by the user, but they didn't seem to impact the speed of the query, so I removed them in this example. But maby instead of simplifying my question I made it less simple, sorry.

Due to those settings users can set, caching is difficult (hundreds of options)... You think it's better if I make a new question with the full query? I figured that as long as this basic example is slow, that needs to be solved first. But I understand now that probably the filters can actually make it faster...

Comment: Filters could provide options for indexing. Paging plus an index could help, too. Both provide options for limiting the size of the result set that the database has to process. Although since you want to sort by the result, paging might still not be enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try
My first suggestion is to do the aggregation before the join:

```
SELECT p.id, p.page_title AS name,
       v.bounce, v.goal,v.volume
FROM pages p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT page_id, sum(v.bounce) as bounce, sum(v.goal) as goal,
             count(*) as volumn
      FROM visitors v
      GROUP BY page_id
     ) v
     ON pages.id = v.page_id
ORDER BY volume DESC;
```

However, your query needs to do both an aggregation and a sort -- and you have no filtering.  I'm not sure you'll be able to get it much faster.

Comment: Thanks. This makes a significant difference. Together with the conclusions from the comments from my post (there is some filtering actually, it wasn't smart from me to simplify the question) I can work it out from here. Thanks!